# Java miscalculation using either double or float

Tags: java, double, decimal

I am trying to make a web application using the following code for the Model part of the MVC pattern:

```
    public OddsCalcBrain(String _odds, String _personalodds, String _bankroll){

    odds = Double.parseDouble(_odds);
    personalodds = Double.parseDouble(_personalodds) / 100.0d;
    personaloddslose = 1.0d-personalodds;
    bankroll = Double.parseDouble(_bankroll);

    result = bankroll * ((odds * personalodds - personaloddslose) / (2.0d * odds));
}

public String getResult(){
    return Double.toString(result);
}
```

I'm using a RequestDispatcher in my servlet to forward the result to a JSP page, it looks like this:

```
     public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response)
 throws ServletException, IOException
 {
     String _personalodds = request.getParameter("personalodds");
     String _odds = request.getParameter("odds");
     String _bankroll = request.getParameter("bankroll");
     OddsCalcBrain brain = new OddsCalcBrain(_personalodds, _odds, _bankroll);

    request.setAttribute("result", brain.getResult());
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/oddscalc.jsp");
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

 }
```

And to print it, i use this:

```
Result: ${result}
```

The result is very miscalculated. For instance, if:

```
odds = 3;
personalodds = 0.5; //(The user would enter a percentage, so 50 would be 0.5)
personaloddslose = 0.5;
bankroll = 120;
```

The formula should produce 20.0 as a result, which it does if I manually put it in a calculator, but no matter if I use float or double for my variables it gives me 0.636 as a result. Why is this, and how can I do it properly?

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: Where is `result` defined?

Comment: The formula  is perfectly working: `System.out.println(120 * ((3 * 0.5 - 0.5) / (2.0d * 3)));` prints out `20.0`

Comment: It is not `(120 * ((3 * 0.5 - 0.5) / (2.0d * 3)))`

`personalodds = Double.parseDouble(_personalodds) / 100.0d;`
will be 0.5 / 100 = 0.005

Comment: @Raphaël read the comment in the code. The user will enter a percentage like 50.

Comment: Right, Just tried it again directly in java, and I do get 20.0

Comment: "... no matter if I use float or double for my variables..."  Don't use `float` for calculations.  The only reason you should ever use `float` is to save space when you have to store huge arrays of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling:

```
OddsCalcBrain brain = new OddsCalcBrain(_personalodds, _odds, _bankroll); 
//OddsCalcBrain("50", "3", "120");
```

Instead of

```
OddsCalcBrain brain = new OddsCalcBrain(_odds, _personalodds, _bankroll);
//OddsCalcBrain("3", "50", "120");
```

Comment: Wow! I'm embarrassed. This was it. Thanks a lot to you and everyone else who helped! Such silly mistakes can cause such great headaches sometimes.

Comment: No problem ! If you don't know how to debug servlets (I don't), you can always debug this type of method in [Junit](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/index.html).